# Amazon Lambda connectivity issue- API calls works sometimes , doesn't work other time

Tags: rest, web-services, aws-lambda

I am using Amazon Lambda to connect to an External Rest web service. My code is in Java

```
URL url = new URL("MYURL");
HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
JsonReader jsonReader = Json.createReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream(), "UTF-8"));
```

The issue is sometimes this code runs perfectly fine, but sometimes, I do not get any response nor any exception. I am not changing anything in my code.

In AWS X-ray under Error and faults - Error comes as True.

How can I possibly debug this issue? or what could I be doing wrong?
Thanks for the help!

Comment: Is there anything in any Cloudwatch logs?

Comment: nothing- Just populating the request ID with the duration and memory size. When I see traces in X-ray it shows error in the status.

Comment: It works fine sometimes, but when I run it later in does not give me any response. My backend Webservice is running absolutely fine.